# Why is the actual number of thumbnail images not matching what is store in an attachments metadata?

Tags: post-meta, thumbnails

Occasionally my plugin needs to delete an image and its thumbnails images. However sometimes there is a discrepancy between the number of thumbnails an attachment has and the number of thumbnail files listed in the attachment metadata record. When this happens there are usually more thumbnails images on the server than specified in the metadata. Would changing themes or plugins cause this? I am not aware of metadata records automatically changing as changes are made to the site.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with thumbnail regeneration.

Comment: Yes, and it's most probably because the thumbnails were regenerated using [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) which stated that "it does not check or delete intermediate sizes it previously created for the same image", and the plugin/theme/code that calls the function didn't automatically delete existing thumbnails.